# Correct $PATHs on .bash_profile for npm packages (Sublime)

Tags: bash, macos, npm, sublimetext3

So I think I somehow messed up my $PATH settings and now only some of my Sublime Text packages are working. For example, I just added Minify (globally), and I can see it in the packages dropdown menu but the commands don't do anything.

From what I can make out so far, there are discrepancies between what is in
./npm-packages/
and
/usr/local/bin

My .bash_profile currently looks like this:

```
source ~/.profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH”
PATH="~/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH”
export PATH
```

I'm not so good when it comes to system operations so if anyone has an idea of what I've done wrong, it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: maybe try changing the "magic closing quotes" `”` to normal quote characters

Comment: `~/.profile` and `$HOME/.profile` are the same file; you are sourcing twice.

Comment: And `~` has to be unquoted to expand to your home directory: `PATH=~/.npm-packages/bin:"$PATH"`. (In the case, though, you could safely omit the double quotes altogether.)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Embarrassed to admit I didn't notice the quote format error...however that doesn't appear to have fixed it. I think it's more down to an incorrect location of the Sublime Text packages. I shall have to do more research...